# Telephone number validator

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi everybody i'm working on the telephone number project i have tried many regex pattern to match the cases but i am still stuck

The user may fill out the form field any way they choose as long as it has the format of a valid US number. The following are examples of valid formats for US numbers (refer to the tests below for other variants):

555-555-5555

(555)555-5555

(555) 555-5555

555 555 5555

5555555555

1 555 555 5555

this is what i tried

```
1([(\s]+\d{3}[)\s])(\d+)$|([\s(\d]\d+[\s|)|-\d])(\d+[\s-\d])+(\d+)$
```

the validator should return false for any case that don't match those above like : 10 (757) 622-7382 or 555)-555-5555

Comment: Nice regex.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Break them down one by one and once they all work combine them.

Comment: You may want to edit the sentence "this is what i tried it work perfectly" : it seems to indicate you have already solved your problem ...

Comment: okay i'll go with this but my regular expression will be very longer to write

Comment: yeah that was a mistake of mine

Comment: @BuhBuh sorry if my post is unclear i'm new to JS, like 45-50 days, and english is not really my native language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(1 )?(\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))[\- ]?\d{3}[\- ]?\d{4}$

^                 start of string
(1 )?             optional "1 "
(
    \d{3}            three digits
    |                or
    \(\d{3}\)        three digits wrapped in parenthasis
)
[\- ]?            optional "- " charactor
\d{3}             three digits
[\- ]?            optional "- " charactor
\d{4}             four digits
$                 end of string
```

[You can see it running here](https://regex101.com/r/oiAJrF/1)

Comment: your solution worked perfectly for me just add to edit a little bit to match this case : 1(555)555-5555

Comment: this what i've came with base on your's : ^(1[\s]?)?(\d{3}|\s\d{3}\s|\(\d{3}\))[\- ]?\d{3}[\- ]?\d{4}$

Comment: space is optional after 1